# In the Quadratic Formula, what does it mean if $b^2-4ac>0$, $b^2-4ac<0$, and $b^2-4ac=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Concerning the Quadratic Formula:

What does it mean if  $b^2-4ac>0$, $b^2-4ac<0$, and $b^2-4ac=0$?

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Those expresions are inequalities, and their content is the discriminant of a quadratic expresion $ax^{2}+bx+c=0$. Can you explain your question please? You could add another flag too, just like "homework" or "algebra-precalculus".

Comment: Due to the nature of the quadratic formula I removed the square root signs in the three inequalities.

Answer (score 10):

$\Delta={ b^2-4ac}>0$  means that the equation has two real solutions.

$\Delta= { b^2-4ac}<0$ means that the equation has no real solutions, but two complex solutions.

$\Delta={ b^2-4ac}=0$ means that the equation has one solution.

Comment: And when it's $0$, the solution is real. I think it's worth pointing out that all of this can be determined by a careful look directly at the quadratic formula and thinking about what happens in each of these cases.

Comment: Yes, you're right!!!

Answer (score 7):

Since one has the term $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ in solution of the quadratic formula, if $b^2-4ac>0$, then the equation has two real solutions (since $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is real, and $b$ and $2a$ are also real). When $b^2-4ac<0$, then the quadratic equation has two complex solutions (since $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is complex imaginary). If $b^2-4ac=0$, then $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=0$, implying that the solution is $x=\dfrac{-b}{2a}$ (can you see why?).

Answer (score 1):

If $ b^2 - 4ac > 0 $ then you will get 2 real roots of the quadratic equation.

If $ b^2 - 4ac < 0  $ then your under root part will become negative and so the equation will have 2 complex roots.

If $ b^2 - 4ac = 0 $ then you will have one solution which will be $ -b/a $

[this might help you understand better](https://www.math-only-math.com/examine-the-roots-of-a-quadratic-equation.html)